# Is `git push origin develop:feature` a safe way to create a branch?

Tags: git

I have long preferred this way instead of copying the branch locally first using `git checkout -b new_branch`. This saves me one command on average as I usually want to have these branches on the remote.

Do you see any problems with this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is safe, but if you want to do any work on that branch, you still have to check it out, so I'm not sure how it saves you a command. Also, after you do work on it you are going to push it to the server anyway, so I'm not sure what the point is of pushing it upon creation.

All that being said, if you want to check it out and push it at the same time, you could create an alias in you config file to do so, e.g.

```
[alias]
  push-new-branch = !sh -c 'git push origin head:$1 && git checkout $1' -
```

then `git push-new-branch feature` will both create it on the server and check it out locally.

Comment: It's because I usually have to switch to the branch I want to copy, copy and check out the branch created. I've later figured you could do this with some additional parameters to the git checkout command. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you see any problems with this method?

If the `feature` branch already exists in the remote repo and the push would be a fast-forward then the command will run without error, but it will actually have updated an existing branch instead of creating a new one.

Almost the same problem also applies if you do `git checkout -b feature && git push` except that if `feature` already exists locally then creating the new branch would fail, and you wouldn't push anything. It would still update the remote if `feature` doesn't exist locally but does exist remotely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JonathanWakely I did not consider this scenario. I accepted the other answer because he has also provided a script, but I upvoted you for the information. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

No, This is normal way.
But i dont know why you need create branch on remote first?
Because we have to develop in local first.

But, if you want to create branch on remote first. Just using create new branch on github or bitbucket.
[image]